# Creating a custom progress bar in flash? (not a preloader)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I need a progress bar that's kind of in an odd shape, I've attached an image. It's not a preloader; it's for periodic progress while the user is performing other action on the website. I've played and played with tweens from a symbol of a fill of the bar to no avail. I'm not great at flash, so apparently even this simple thing is a stumbling block for me. Since it's an odd shape,

I was hoping I could somehow use a paint bucket fill of the symbol or something like that to create "progress", and simply send a "stop" command when it's at the appropriate level, but I've tried several different ways and just don't have the ability to do it. I can't seem to find anything online that's even close either. I'd sure appreciate being pointed in the right direction!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tried tweening a filled rectangle behind your shape and use your shape as a mask.

Comment: This is why I love you guys. I'll get the hang of this flash sooner or later. Thanks a lot, PatrickS! I need to think more creatively I guess.